# How create something like mqtt-broker helper in node-red

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node-red

When we adding the mqtt-in or mqtt-out nodes we obtain a server field with select list and a button which can add new servers to the list
 [image: img].
Please, help me change the functionality of the button with pencil instead of default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's known as a config node, how to create config nodes is described in the Node-RED documentation here: https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/config-nodes

The important bit is the type of the of the config option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  RED.nodes.registerType('mqtt in',{
    category: 'input',
    defaults: {
      name: {value:""},
      topic: {value:"",required:true,validate: RED.validators.regex(/^(#$|(\+|[^+#]*)(\/(\+|[^+#]*))*(\/(\+|#|[^+#]*))?$)/)},
      qos: {value: "2"},
      broker: {type:"mqtt-broker", required:true}
    },
    color:"#d8bfd8",
    inputs:0,
    outputs:1,
    ...
```

As you can see the `broker` field has a type of `mqtt-broker`. The `mqtt-broker` node is a separate node with a category of `config`.

There are plenty of examples of this type of pattern in the core nodes that ship with Node-RED including the MQTT or serial port nodes.